# Bithacking comparison (less) operator

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

I am aware that most arithmetical operations can be done only using bitwise operators ([Add two integers using only bitwise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068033/add-two-integers-using-only-bitwise-operators), [Multiplication of two integers using bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456442/interview-multiplication-of-2-integers-using-bitwise-operators), etc ...).

I am also aware, that if you have the less operator you can deduce the other operators from it ([Sorting only using the less-than operator compared to a trivalue compare function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385690/sorting-only-using-the-less-than-operator-compared-to-a-trivalue-compare-functio))

So ... I am simply curios if there is a way of implementing the less operator using only bitwise operations.

Like:

```
bool less(int a, int b) { ??? }
```

And to make it more complicated:

```
template<typename T> bool less(T a, T b) { ??? }
```

where T certainly is an integral, numerical type (8 ... 64 bit)

Answer (score 3):

It can certainly be done. Assuming two's complement:

```
bool less(int a, int b)
{
  const unsigned int bits = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;
  const unsigned int sign_bit = 1u << (bits - 1);
  unsigned int lhs = a;
  unsigned int rhs = b;
  bool negative = (lhs & sign_bit);
  if (negative && !(rhs & sign_bit))
    return negative;
  for (unsigned int bit == 1u << (bits - 2); bit != 0u; bit >>= 1) {
    if ((lhs & bit) != (rhs & bit)) {
      return !(lhs & bit);
    }
  }
}
```

The template version could work the same, with the help of an appropriate `make_unsigned<T>` trait.