# std::sort function gives "Bus error: 10"

Tags: c++, struct, stl

Following code gives "Bus error: 10", though it works perfectly when n is changed to 30. I REALLY do NOT see any single reason for that error. Why do you think this is happening?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#define MAX 100000
using namespace std;

struct suffix
{
    int cur;
};

suffix suffixes[MAX];

bool cmp(suffix a, suffix b)
{
    return (a.cur <= b.cur);
}

int main()
{
   int n = 1000;
   sort(suffixes,suffixes + n,cmp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What platform/OS are you using? How much RAM is in your machine?

Comment: MacOS, 2.7GHz dual-core Intel Core i5, 8 GB RAM

Comment: `sort` needs a compare function that does monotonic sorting. Change `<=` to `<` and see if that helps. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385690/sorting-only-using-the-less-than-operator-compared-to-a-trivalue-compare-functio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compare function has a problem. It doesn't satisfy [the requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) expected by `std::sort`. It needs to give a *strict weak ordering*, it must return `false` for equivalent elements. Try changing it to:

```
bool cmp(suffix a, suffix b)
{
    return (a.cur < b.cur); // note comparison is < instead of <=
}
```

Comment: It actually helps, thanks. But why do you think there is a threshold like 35?

Comment: @Enes: If you violate the algorithm's prerequisites it can lead to undefined behavior. Crashing is one possible result, the specific threshold isn't that important.

Comment: @Enes - FYI, if you used the Visual C++ compiler, this error would have been detected (in the debug runtime) and your program would have stopped with an assertion.  The way Visual C++ checks this is to call your `cmp` function twice -- the first time with (a,b), and a second time with (b,a).  If you gave an answer of `true` for both calls, the runtime asserts.  The reason is that there is no way `a < b`, and at the same time `b < a`.